# JavaScript error no Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the error in this questions's title from [this page](http://www.problemio.com/index_new.php). It isn't a page users see. It is a test page I am working on and I copied the general template from [here](http://www.problemio.com/).

For some reason the latter doesn't get this error and the former does. I checked and I am pretty sure I am importing all the same libraries, so why does the new page give this error?

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen a lot of questions asked about Problemio. Ironically, it sounds like you're having a lot of issues developing your site :-(

Comment: @JamWaffles :) well, I am the only developer doing front-end and back-end and database work...and I have to market this thing too. So I can't afford to be stuck on any one thing for too long. As it is I am putting nearly all my waking time into it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `index_new` includes

http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js

Which overwrites/interferes with the normal `.dialog` method.

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to make these libraries play nice together? I'd like to try the jQuery Tooltip library.

Comment: @Genadinik I'm afraid I don't know. You could try including the tooltip plugin _before_ jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

You have this block of code:

```
var $dialog = $('#loginpopup')
  .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Login Dialog'
  });
```

`$('#loginpopup')` is returning an HTML element (a <div/>, specifically), and these don't have any build-in methods called `dialog`.

Comment: his standard libraries _do_ define a dialog method. It's the additional include that is removing it.

Comment: @ziesemer not sure I understand. My confusion is that these 2 pages have similar JS imported. Why does one have it and the other not have that error? :)

Comment: @Shad you mean the tooltip library that is causing this problem?

Comment: oh yeah OMG it was the tooltip library. Wouldn't have thought that jQuery libraries would conflict each other. Thanks!!

Comment: @Genadinik - See Shad's answer (+1 for it from me).